# asp.net with java backend

Tags: java, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a full java web application stack (J2EE web app using Spring and Hibernate with a RIA client using dojo).
I have to move technology stacks for the UI to be asp.net but am allowed to keep the server components in java.
Any ideas on best practice here - and yes, I have to adopt this hybrid tech stack.
Initial thoughts are:

asp.net ajax (possibly using asp.net MVC) to provide the UI and a thin control layer in IIS.
expose current java web app (residing on a remote machine) as RESTful web services (the web app would remain in a J2EE serlet container such as Tomcat or Jetty). The new control layer would provide security (authentication and authorisation), comet server push abilities and then basic request passthrough to the web app.

Basically, I am unsure 'how much' C# I should write in the control layer and how best to expose and communicate with the existing java web app. Also, currently, I use JSON as the data interchange format.

Comment: i cannot think of a single reason why these two different stacks needs to be used together...its mind blowing why such a requirement exists...

Comment: Where are you using JSON now - is it for ajax calls from existing web app to the server? If so, does that API cover (to what extent) the needs for communication between new asp.net app and the java app?

Comment: @Chii: People. They are very expensive, and if you have a Java backend guy and an ASP.NET front end guy then this is a natural fit.

Comment: @Chii: Years worth of work invested into java set of services. New corporate standard for UI - not my decision.
@Robert: JSON is used to communicate between the dojo ajax app and the java web application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start moving to asp.net feature by feature, don't try to implement everything at once.

Comment: @ZippyV: I would do a phased migration but my question really relates to 'what' and 'where' to implement code rather than 'how'.